# How to move files based on first word in file name?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, filename

In a folder, I have thousand of files, such as:

```
cat eats mouse.jpg
cat chases mouse.jpg
gorilla eats banana.jpg
gorilla is sleeping.jpg
elephant is huge.jpg
elephant has trunk.jpg
(and so on...)
```

I want a bash script that will move these files based on the first word in the file name (cat, gorilla, elephant, etc) into folders, also created based on the first word, so that:

- 'cat' folder is created and all files that begin with 'cat' are moved into this folder.
- 'gorilla' folder is created and all files that begin with 'gorilla' are moved into this folder.
- 'elephant' folder is created and all files that begin with elephant are moved into this folder.
- (And so on..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following oneliner should do the job:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec perl -e '$a="{}"; $a =~ /(\w+)/; `mkdir -p $1 && mv "$a" $1`' \;
```

**Explanation**

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg'` will look for files (`-type f`) only in the current folder (`. -maxdepth 1`) with the jpg extension.
- `-exec` will call the `perl` command for every matching files. The string `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed.
- `$a="{}";` saves the current file
- `$a =~ /(\w+)/` is a regular expression test, the special variable `$1` will contain the first word of the filename stored in `$a`.
- finally `mkdir -p $1 && mv "$a" $1` is executed as a system command with `/bin/sh` or its equivalent. Note the `-p` option of `mkdir`, it won't fail if the directory already exists.

[image]

---

**Update**

To prevent code injection in perl (thanks @[geirha](https://askubuntu.com/users/9016/geirha)), use the [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function as follow:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec perl -e '$a="\Q@ARGV"; $a =~ /(\w+)/; `mkdir -p $1 && mv $a $1`' "{}" \;
```

Comment: *["I have minimal knowledge in scripting, so be easy on me."](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/538269/1)* can you explain for him/her? Thanks

Comment: @KasiyA: Done, sorry I was a bit in a hurry on Friday.

Comment: I know, all we can not reply quickly and I didn't downvote, but +1 Thanks

Comment: Note that it fails if the filename contains `"` quotes. This is because you inject data into code, which is something you generally want to avoid (think Bobby Tables). Even worse, it may run arbitrary code by specially crafted filenames: e.g. if you run `touch 'dog ".\`mktemp\`.".jpg'` before that find command, `mktemp` will actually be run.

Comment: @geirha: Thanks a lot for this warning. I've updated my answer to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a for loop for this.

```
for file in ./*" "*.jpg; do
    word=${file%% *}
    mkdir -p "$word" &&
    mv "$file" "$word"
done
```

You can run this in an interactive shell, or put it in a script. Bash is very useful to know, so I recommend learning it by reading the [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) when you have the time.